# Disagreement between Rydberg Equation and Conservation of momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

I have a physics question as my homework and it is as follows:
At what minimum kinetic energy must a hydrogen atom move for its inelastic head-on collision with another, stationary, hydrogen atom to make one of them capable of emitting a photon? both atoms are in ground state before the collision

Attempt 1 at solution:
I simply used the Rydberg Equation for hydrogen
$$\Delta E=E_0(\frac{1}{n_f^2}-\frac{1}{n_i^2})$$
Where $E_0=13.6eV$, I simply plug in the numbers to obtain the numerical solution of $10.2eV$

Attempt 2 at solution:
I consider conservation of momentum and energy 
$$E=hf$$
$$p=\frac{hc}{f}$$
Therefore:
$$p_{photon}=p_{H}$$
$$\frac{hc}{f}=p_{H}$$
$$(1)\hspace{5 mm}f=\frac{hc}{p_H}$$
We also know by COE:
$$E_{photon}=E_{H}$$
$$(2)\hspace{5 mm}hf=\frac{p_H^2}{2m_H}$$
Substituting $(1)$ into $(2)$
we obtain
$$\frac{h^2c}{p_H}=\frac{p_H^2}{2m_H}$$
$$\frac{h^2c}{2m_H}=p_h^3$$
Momentum of the hydrogen atom is therefor:
$$\qquad \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{2}\scriptstyle 3]{2h^2m_Hc}=p_h$$
Solving for$E_{H}$
$$\frac{\sqrt[3]{2h^2m_Hc}}{2m_H}$$
Solving numericallyy this leads to a disagreement as the solution using COM is $3.9696\times10^{-37}eV$ which is obviously wrong....
Did I mess up somewhere in the COM method or is it completely wrong?

Comment: Conservation of energy implies that the net energy after is same as the net energy before. It does not imply that the kinetic energies of the photon and atom are equal initially.

Comment: I didn't see the kinetic energy of the hydrogen atom in your equations.

Comment: @freude it wasn't needed as they asked for the energy of the hydrogen atom, I only need the equation for energy of a photon